# Can I set dwm.exe to run on integrated GPU?

Tags: windows-10, gpu, windows-10-v1803

I've seen [this article](https://pureinfotech.com/set-gpu-app-windows-10/) about specifying the gpu to use for each program, and I've started doing this to get some load off of my dedicated GPU so that only games run on it. Now I see that there is still dwm.exe, which is the system process for deskop windows.

Can I set this run on the integrated GPU safely?